# Docker Unable to open configuration file

Tags: docker

**Problem**:

I have docker container running with squid. 
Is running correctly until I expose volume.

Runs fine when I start the container like this:

```
 docker run --name squid -d -p 3128:3128 leros321/squid_proxy:latest
```

but fails when I provide the configuration file from the host:

```
docker run --name squid -d -p 3128:3128 -v /root/squid/squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf leros321/squid_proxy:latest
```

I am getting:

> error code (journalctl -xe):
>
> FATAL: Unable to open configuration file: /etc/squid/squid.conf: (13)
>   Permission denied

Rights inside container:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 squid    squid         2369 Jul 24 06:44 /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

Squid id: /

```
# id squid
uid=31(squid) gid=31(squid) groups=31(squid),31(squid),1000(winbind)
```

Rights on host:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 31 root 2484 Jul 24 08:27 /root/squid/squid.conf
```

Comment: Please format your question properly so that it becomes easy to understand.

Comment: Can you try running the container as the squid user, by adding `--user squid` to the docker run command?

Comment: Thanks it helped